# How to display activedataprovider data in gridview yii2

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

My array

```
 $data = [
        'subcategoryName' => 'asd',
        'fromdate' => $fromdate,
        'todate' => $todate,
        'amount' => $finalamount,

        ];
```

Array data provider

```
  $provider = new ArrayDataProvider([
    'allModels' => $data,
    'pagination' => [
        'pageSize' => 10,
    ],
    'sort' => [
        'attributes' => ['subcategoryName'],
    ],
]);

// get the rows in the currently requested page
$rows = $provider->getModels();
        return $rows;
```

Now I want to display this data on my grid view but I am getting this error Call to a member function getCount() on array

Please tell me that how can I display my array on yii2 grid view

Comment: Update your question and add  also the view /gridview code

Answer (score 2):

You should'nt return here result of function `getModels()`. I assume u pass this to `GridView`, but u have to pass `ArrayDataProvider`.

Change this:

```
$rows = $provider->getModels();
return $rows;
```

To this:

```
return $provider;
```